# Selenium Webdriver store cookies and use them c#

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, cookies

I want to store cookies of a website (for login), close the driver and start a new driver and use the cookies in the new browser (because I want to control the website headless).

Using C#, Selenium and Chrome

I've tried:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("websiteXY");

//...Waits here for User input and goes after input on...

var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies; 
driver.Close();

driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("websiteXY");

foreach (Cookie ck in cookies)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ck); //gets no output here
    driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(ck);
}
```

There is no error, except one because it can't login (no cookies) and doesn't find the elemets it is searching for.

Comment: in your code you close the driver and create a new one , then access the old cookies??

Answer (score 0):

First verify, if after you saved your cookies, using this line: `var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;`, does `cookies` contain any data?

Comment: I printed `Console.WriteLine(cookies.Count)` Output is 0

Comment: Then, seems, like you are not taking cookies properly. First do this part, then you continue with putting cookies into new browser.

Comment: And how do I get them?

Comment: I would start with validation, if cookies present in the site at that time, when you are trying to get them. If not, then find out, at which page/state they present.