# Selenium - login skip

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation

Is there a way to skip page login using Selenium? I am able to generate access token on backend for login, but I am not sure how to use it with Selenium afterwards. I get the access token based on client id and client secret.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a cookie?
It totally depends on the site but export the cookie and loading it into selenium is often a good solution.
[Selenium Webdriver store cookies and use them c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600962/selenium-webdriver-store-cookies-and-use-them-c-sharp)